# Access SQL Subquery to find a value from the previous year record (Max/Top minus 1)

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, query

All the advice I was able to locate doesn't seem to get at this (I am also trying to avoid a DLookup in the **Table** itself):

The table: **Table** has client records including a **Year** field, an **AppointmentDate** field and a **ClientName** field (which has identical values for each individual client across all years). (Table's client IDs for each record are expectedly random.)

In an MS Access Query that shows a sampling of this year's clients (by **ClientName** and delimited by a few other factors), need to also show the value of **AppointmentDate** from the previous year's (max **Year** minus 1) record for the same client.

Subquery attempts such as the below do not work:

LastYearApptDate:

```
(SELECT AppointmentDate FROM (SELECT (AppointmentDate) FROM Table ORDER BY Year DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY AppointmentDate ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Nor have the online suggested *Top* attempts shown the expected result.

(I realize *Max* is not supported in MS Access.)

Perhaps I am missing something about Access's syntax for a SQL subquery (via the  "Zoom" Dialogue).

Answer (score 1):

Below solved by:

```
SELECT Table.AppointmentDate
FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.ClientName=[Client]) AND ((Year=(SELECT Max(Table.Year) AS PreviousYear
FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.Year)<(SELECT MAX(Table.Year) FROM Table WHERE ((Table.ClientName=[Client]))))))));
```

Now the challenge is to merge this with Client fields (like AppointmentDate) from the Table per the most recent year - and to show this for each client. Is there any way to do this without a UNION?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of different attempts at just entering SQL into Access, still missing something important:

Here are the Pieces so far (okay, so MAX appears to work despite documentation that said otherwise):

```
SELECT MAX(Table.Year) 
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Year<(SELECT MAX(Table.Year) FROM Table)
```

The above correctly selects the previous year (generally for Table).

The previous year for a particular client can be isolated thus:

```
SELECT Max(Table.Year) AS PreviousYear
FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.Year)<(SELECT MAX(Table.Year) FROM Table WHERE ((Table.ClientName)=[Client]))));
```

Where "Client" is, for now, just entered manually.

Now the challenge is to select the AppointmentDate value from the previous year's record by way of a common ClientName (and the above PreviousYear value for each ClientName - the PreviousYear values will be different for each Client) - this is where I seem to be missing something important:

```
SELECT Table.AppointmentDate
FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.ClientName=[Client])) AND ((Table.Year)=(SELECT MAX(Table.Year) AS LastDueDate FROM Table WHERE (((Table.Year)<(SELECT MAX(Table.Year) FROM Table WHERE ((Table.ClientName)=[Client]))))));
```

Not sure what's missing, tried: FROM Table t ...

Any insights would be appreciated - thanks!